# Azure WebAPI only for users of Office365?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure, office365, asp.net-core-webapi

I have setup a basic Web API on Azure. (With C# and VS 2019 and ASP.NET CORE 2.2)
So far, the API is running and I can run various actions.

Now I want to achieve that only people who have logged into an account in Office 365 can access my API. How can this be done?

Comment: A tutorial: https://joonasw.net/view/azure-ad-authentication-aspnet-core-api-part-1

Comment: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=Azure+AD+Protect+WebAPI&t=brave&ia=web

Comment: @JackJia Write it as an answer, and I can upvote it.

Answer (score 1):

Generally , Office 365 users use Azure Active Directory as an identity provider to auth users to access O365 services . For details about its relation ship, you can refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/enterprise/about-office-365-identity).

So you can just use Azure AD to protect your web api . 
This is an [Azure official .net core demo](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-openidconnect-aspnetcore) which integrated with Azure AD will be helpful for you . 
You can find more Azure AD samples [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/sample-v1-code).

Comment: Thanks, that's what I wanted, just some guide. I will look at it and comment back again.

Comment: @askolotl welcome ! Pls mark me if my suggestions are helpful : )